# How to require node_modules from my own Laravel project packages

Tags: laravel, package, node-modules

I'm setting up my own Laravel Package, and want to create dependancies to some node_modules. How can they be required in the composer.json of my package for this is not linked to the node_modules.

Used Git Bash to install to create my package in the packages/my/project/ folder and my composer.json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "my/project",
    "description": "Description.",
    "keywords": [
      "front-end",
      "framework"
    ],

...

    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.0"
    },
```

I want te require from node_modules: @vue/component-compiler-utils

Comment: Why would you want to include JavaScript assets in your PHP dependency manager?

Comment: I suppose I could ask the question the other way around, where should I create my own node.js package with proper dependancies to other node_modules? This looked like the propper way to do it.

Comment: I guess this would help as starting point: https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-node-js-modules . The rest (i.e. "where should I" and "proper dependencies") is really subjective and not really a question to ask here. Try some stuff out and see what works and doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can require them in package.json file in your root directory and then run a `npm install`. And then add them to your app.js or bootstrap.js file under resources/js and run a `npm run production`.

Comment: You're right... almost created my own npm module to import some other modules.. No need to keep my code in /packages, resources will suffice I guess?

Comment: Could you document how to add node modules into bootstrap.js file in a package?